# multiple socket connection is establishing when refresh

Tags: express, socket.io

```
function authenticateUser(io, socket, next) {
    const token = socket.handshake.query.token // Assume you're passing a token in the handshake
    console.log(token)
    // Your authentication logic here, e.g., verify the token and fetch user information

    let tokenResult = jsonwebtoken.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
    if (tokenResult) {
        const userId = tokenResult.id
        const existingSocketId = users.get(userId)

        if (existingSocketId) {
            console.log('exisiting user')
            console.log(existingSocketId)

            io.sockets.sockets.get(existingSocketId)?.disconnect(true)

            users.set(userId, socket.id)
        } else {
            console.log('new user')
            // If it's a new connection, simply add it to the map
            users.set(userId, socket.id)
        }

        console.log(users)
        socket.user = userId

        return next()
    } else {
        // If authentication fails, reject the connection
        return next(new Error('Authentication failed'))
    }
}
```

this is server socket code i need to delete the existing socket session when the client reconnect but the old session is not deleted.